# EF Code First: "Required" not added in NOT NULL int column after Code First generation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I added a model via Code First, but [Required] annotation was not added for the int column, only for the Varchar column. I am trying to make the column required using @Html.ValidationMessageFor. Is there any way to force it to add in the int column?

```
    [LastName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL, 

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }


    [JobId] [int]  NOT NULL,

    public int JobId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Nullable integers are `int?`. `int` can not be null.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I was wondering if Required annnotation might be needed for the MVC validation though. I am new to MVC, but will look into it.

Comment: int will default to 0 so it will always have a value. you can specify a range if needed depending on your use case

Comment: If you don't want zero valid you could try `[Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a value bigger than {1}")]`

Comment: @marc_s, you are correct, it should be EF, not MVC, I got it wrong but fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Required] is not needed since int is not null.

Validation will still work even without having to add [Required] annotation.

Therefore [Required] annotation is not necessary:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobId)
```

> The JobId field is required.